# Categorize rows depending on group size

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

For context reasons imagine an internet forum with threads and posts. Every thread and every post has it's own unique identifier.
Further, multiple posts can be linked to a thread (you could also imagine people(=posts) and the families(=threads) that they belong to):

I have a dataframe in pandas with two columns: `thread_id` and `post_id`.
Every row in my dataframe is a post in this forum. The `thread_id` shows to which thread the post belongs to and `post_id` shows the posts' unique identifier.

I now want to add a third column: `thread_size`. It shows to which kind of thread the post belongs.
This column has one of three different values: `small`, `medium` or `big`. The value is chosen depending on, you guessed it, the thread's size. There are two thresholds (upper and lower) by which a thread's size is measured.

i tried to group the posts by thread and then set the `thread_size`-size using a for loop and if, elif, else statements. But it does not seem to work:

```py
forum["thread_size"] = np.nan

for thread_id, frame in forum.groupby(["thread_id"]):
    post_count = frame.size
    if post_count > 400:
        frame["thread_size"] = "big"
    elif post_count > 300:
        frame["thread_size"] = "medium"
    else:
        frame["thread_size"] = "small"
```

**EDIT:**
Think of the `forum` as a city(the dataframe) with people that belong to families. Every row in my dataframe represents a person (post) that belongs to a family (thread). I want to extend the city-dataframe with a column named `family-size`. This way every person (row) has now the information to which family they belong and if they belong to a `big`, `medium` or `small` family:
Before:

```
[name]    [family]   
 oscar     potter       
 frederic  minamisawa  
 blerim    meier       
 marina    minamisawa
```

After:

```
[name]    [family]     [family-size]
 oscar     potter       small
 frederic  minamisawa   big
 blerim    meier        medium
 marina    minamisawa   big
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what i wanted:

```
thread_category = lambda x: 2 if x > 400 else (1 if x > 300 else 0)

forum["thread_size"] = forum.groupby('thread_id')["post_id"].transform(lambda x: thread_category(len(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.cut` to put them into bins. First some mock data:

```
n = 1000
np.random.seed(2)

# I want to bias the threads such that thread 1 has a decent chance
# of being "large", 2 is "medium" and 3 and 4 are "small"
thread_id = np.random.choice([1,2,3,4], size=n, p=[0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1])

# post_id is unique, may as well be sequential
post_id = np.arange(n)

# The dataframe
forum = pd.DataFrame({
    'thread_id': thread_id,
    'post_id': post_id
})
```

Now onto your problem:

```
stat = forum.groupby('thread_id').size().to_frame('count')
stat['size'] = pd.cut(stat['count'], [0, 300, 400, np.inf], labels=['small', 'medium', 'large'])
```

The `pd.cut` function cuts the `stat['count']` series into 3 bin:

- (0 - 300]: small
- (300 - 400]: medium
- (400 - inf]: large

Result:

```
           count    size
thread_id               
1            416   large
2            313  medium
3            165   small
4            106   small
```

Comment: how do you map this information to every row in the `forum` dataframe? Like going through every row, looking at its `thread_id`, find the `thread_id` in `stat` and then set the `thread_size` in `forum` depending on the thread-size info stored in `stat`.